# How to handle dynamic tables in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, dynamic-data

we have requirement like below :

For each customer will upload different files having different columns, column names are different from one client to another client and change in the number columns also.

For that one we will stored all the details in one table like

column1,column2,column3 ...........columnN

And will store column mapping some other table

First name=column1

Second Name=Column2

like this, up to this is ok ,but if we are using entity framework how stronly types will work in this case.

In the front end will show the combox box which will display all the client and we will show the data in the grid

Here is important thing is we have to show the End user column name instead our column name like column1,column2

Out put sholud be like below

Combox box ---- Client name

Grid

```
First name   Second Name

---------------------------------

Harish         Kumar
```

Answer (score 1):

EF is not good choice for this type of application. It will map exactly what you have in database - one big entity with `Column1`, `Column2`, etc. properties and one entity with properties like `ColumnName`, `PropertyName`. That is all because EF doesn't support advanced data driven mapping.

Your UI / logic will need some logic to correctly interpret these data and moreover it will also have to correctly transform user input and actions back to EF understandable form.

Imho using EF for this is overhead, use ADO.NET directly. Also check SharePoint because it has this already implemented.